# Ad blockers causing optimizely to fail

Tags: optimizely

I was asked to fix the optimizely issues with ad blockers. I am using optimizely full stack . But the issue is that even after adding ad blocker i am not seeing any issues. Can someone help to replicate the issues with ad blockers ?
Is there any scenario where these issues can be replicated .

Answer (score 1):

Just add *cdn.optimizely.com* to the list of blocked sites in the ad-blocker settings.